# How does Virtual COM on "st-link v3 MINIE" work?

Tags: serial-port, stm32, st-link

I got a st-link v3 MINIE, it has a nice feature of virtual COM on it, but it seems doesn't work properly.

The debugger part work fine, and windows detected it as a com port, but I couldn't get the echo when I connect TX and RX pins. Here are my findings:

- I tried more than one, all are the same
- There is no voltage on TX neither TX pin of st-link v3 MINIE
- Pullup 33k resistor to 3.3 volt, bring the signal to 3.3volt, but it doesn't make it work
- I couldn't find any schematic on web
- I tried to test different FW for st-link, no success (V 2-38-27, 3-9-3, 3-10-3 was tested)

Comment: If you are using terminal software to try to echo characters, make sure that hardware flow-control is disabled.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Good point, I forgot to mention, I tried to get echo by connecting RX to TX with no hardware flow control, but no success

Comment: "*I couldn't get the echo when I connect TX and RX pins*" -- That's not specific enough. Exactly which "*pins*" are you referring to? How did you try to "*get the echo*"?

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect RX to your target TX.
2. Connect TX to your target RX.
3. Configure the baud rate in your target to some value
4. Configure the baud rate in your PC (terminal program) to the same value
5. Enjoy

If something does not work you screw up one of the steps.